# How to retrieve CPU time of a thread inside kernel?

Tags: windows, windows-kernel

From my legacy driver, I'm calling PsCreateSystemThread API to create few threads.
Since this call is happening from inside the kernel, these new created threads will run in the context of System process.

My question is given the handle to these threads, is there any API using which I can fetch their CPU time? I'm interested in the pure CPU time for which thread was actually doing something(similar to kerneltime that we get by calling GetProcessTimes). I know there's an API called GetThreadTimes but that is from User mode, I want CPU time inside the kernel mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are not documented API to get the CPU times of a thread in kernel (since I know). But you can access to the field of the `KTHREAD` structure: `UserTime` and `KernelTime`. The problem with this approach is, mainly, `KTHREAD` is not officially documented and can vary with the OS version.

Answer (score 0):

User-mode `GetThreadTimes` API in fact only calls `NtQueryInformationThread`.
You can do the same:

```cpp
KERNEL_USER_TIMES times;
ZwQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadTimes, &times, sizeof(times), NULL);
```

Both `ThreadTimes` and `KERNEL_USER_TIMES` are defined in *ntddk.h* header in WDK.